# React autocomplete bar from API response not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, axios, material-ui

I'm trying to make an autocomplete/autosuggest search bar from **Material-UI** through an API response. Here's the codebase annex by annex.

We are defining our options of the autosuggest search bar from the given coinlist API provided. We are defining our options state as well here.

```
function MainInput() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [options, setOptions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get(`https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/all/coinlist`)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res.data.Data);
                setOptions(res.data.Data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }, []);
```

Now in the docs from **Material-UI** for the `<Autocomplete />` component. We are supposed to defined our options within the `options` prop. Theoretically, everything should be fine right? Well, the react app loads fine at first but when I click the searchbar everything disappears from the screen. Can anyone pitch any ideas?

```
return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Autocomplete
                id='combo-box-demo'
                options={options}
                getOptionLabel={(options) => options}
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField {...params} label='Combo box' variant='outlined' />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here is what the raw API response looks like for you guys to have an idea.

```
"Response": "Success",
    "Message": "Coin list succesfully returned!",
    "Data": {
        "42": {
            "Id": "4321",
            "Url": "/coins/42/overview",
            "ImageUrl": "/media/35650717/42.jpg",
            "ContentCreatedOn": 1427211129,
            "Name": "42",
            "Symbol": "42",
            "CoinName": "42 Coin",
            "FullName": "42 Coin (42)",
            "Algorithm": "Scrypt",
            "ProofType": "PoW/PoS",
            "FullyPremined": "0",
            "TotalCoinSupply": "42",
            "BuiltOn": "N/A",
            "SmartContractAddress": "N/A",
            "DecimalPlaces": 0,
            "PreMinedValue": "N/A",
            "TotalCoinsFreeFloat": "N/A",
            "SortOrder": "34",
            "Sponsored": false,
            "Taxonomy": {
                "Access": "",
                "FCA": "",
                "FINMA": "",
                "Industry": "",
                "CollateralizedAsset": "",
                "CollateralizedAssetType": "",
                "CollateralType": "",
                "CollateralInfo": ""
            },
            "Rating": {
                "Weiss": {
                    "Rating": "",
                    "TechnologyAdoptionRating": "",
                    "MarketPerformanceRating": ""
                }
            },
            "IsTrading": true,
            "TotalCoinsMined": 41.9999522,
            "BlockNumber": 200520,
            "NetHashesPerSecond": 0,
            "BlockReward": 0,
            "BlockTime": 0
        },{...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your **Data** coming from **API RESPONSE**.
According to **Material-UI**, the parameter you pass to **options** should be in an **Array** but your one is an **Object**.

Please convert the **Data** type to **Array** instead of **Object** and it will work!

```
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <Autocomplete
                id='combo-box-demo'
                options={options} // this should be in An Array
                getOptionLabel={(option) =>option} //go through one option at a time
                style={{ width: 300 }}
                renderInput={(params) => (
                    <TextField {...params} label='Combo box' variant='outlined' />
                )}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Please check the Official Docs of Material-UI
https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

Comment: Thanks. did an Object.entries conversion and it worked fine.